# Is it possible to get a list of games someone owns on xbox via their gamertag?

Tags: api, xbox

Given a gamertag that has public privacy settings, is it possible for me to programatically access the games they purchased?

I'm trying to build an "import your xbox games" features so someone can just type in their gamertag and I can get all of their games for their collection.